# Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSON' Httpclient GET

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Hello i am working on an Angular 6 + Flask application and I have this issue:

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JSON'.`

when my code does that :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MessageService } from '../shared/message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-network-monitorer',
  templateUrl: './network-monitorer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./network-monitorer.component.css']
})
export class NetworkMonitorerComponent implements OnInit {

  mqttMessageData : JSON[]=[];
  coapMessageData : JSON[]=[];
  xmppMessageData : JSON[]=[];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private messageService:MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.getMqttMessages(); },2000);
  }

  getMqttMessages() {
    this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/messages/mqtt').subscribe(data => {
      this.mqttMessageData.push(data);
      console.log("message :")
      console.log(this.mqttMessageData.length())
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

So basically when the component is loading i make a request to my python server to fetch some data which are returned to the client in JSON, but angular seems to think that 'data' is type of Object so i can't add it to my list of JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to cast it:

```
this.httpClient.get<JSON[]>('http://127.0.0.1:5002/messages/mqtt').subscribe(data => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the data to JSON. 
Try using data.json  as demonstrated below.

```
getMqttMessages() {
this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/messages/mqtt').subscribe(data => {
  this.mqttMessageData.push(data.json);
  console.log("message :")
  console.log(this.mqttMessageData.length())
  console.log(data);
});
}
```